# What does this Node.js code which seemingly replaces a function implementation inside the same function do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I'm trying to debug a huge bunch of Node.js code and the following looks insane to me (because of my C++ and C# experience). There's a lot of functions that look like this:

```
function _builderUtil() {
    const data = require("builder-util");
    _builderUtil = function () {
        return data;
    };
    return data;
}
```

... and I have no idea what to search for to get further details.

Here's what I see here... There's a function called `_builderUtil()` and inside it there's a `require()` call which should load a specified module. Then there's a second `_builderUtil` something inside the function. It looks like a variable holding a reference to an anonymous function. Or maybe this replaces the outer function implementation.

What's the purpose of this inner function (one that looks anonymous)? What does this code do and how is this called in Node.js so I know what to search for?

Answer (score 3):

> Or maybe this replaces the outer function implementation.

That's what it's doing. The first time you call `_builderUtil`, it does the `require` call and saves the result in the local `data` constant. Then it overwrites the function that did that with one that just returns that `data` constant. (The `data` constant survives because the inner function closes over it.)

Basically, it lazy-loads the data via `require`, then returns the same data every time you call it after it's loaded.

As CertainPerformance points out in a comment, it's unnecessary. Node.js's module system maintains a cache of loaded modules, so instead of calling `_builderUtil`, it would be sufficient just to use `require("builder-util")` each time you want the data.

But getting back to how it works and ignoring the details of `require`:

Initially, you have something like this in memory:

```
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
_builderUtil−−−−−>| (function) |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                  | [code]     |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

The first time you call it, a *lexical environment object* is created for the locals for the call to the function. Inside that environment object there's the `data` constant, which is initialized with the result of calling `require` (presumably some data). Just after the `const data = require("builder-util");` call and before the `_builderUtil =` after it, you have:

```
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
_builderUtil−−−−−>| (function) |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                  | [code]     |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−+

                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                  | (env object) |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                  | data         |−−−−−>| (some data) |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Then the function overwrites `_builderUtil` with a new function that just returns `data`. Functions have a link to the environment object where they were created, so once the call is done you have this:

```
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                  | (function) |  (the old function, ready to be garbage−collected)
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                  | [code]     |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−+

                         +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                         |                               |
                         v                               |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                       |
                  | (env object) |                       |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
                  | data         |−−−−−>| (some data) |  |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
                                                         |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                      |
_builderUtil−−−−−>|   (function)  |                      |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                      |
                  | [environment] |−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                  | [code]        |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Eventually garbage collection occurs and you have just

```
                         +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                         |                               |
                         v                               |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                       |
                  | (env object) |                       |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
                  | data         |−−−−−>| (some data) |  |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
                                                         |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                      |
_builderUtil−−−−−>|   (function)  |                      |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                      |
                  | [environment] |−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                  | [code]        |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Comment: Seems strange though, why not just `function _builderUtil() {
    return require("builder-util");
}`? Multiple `require` calls don't run the other module's top-level code again, right? What's the point of saving it in a variable and reassigning the function? (Unless `builder-util` reassigns its exports after initialization, so the initial value needs to be saved, which is *really* strange)

Comment: @CertainPerformance - Yeah, I suspect whoever wrote it didn't understand Node.js's module cache. :-) **Or**, they wanted to create an abstraction so that you don't have to remember the name `"builder-util"` (vs. `"builderutil"` or `"builder-utils"`, etc.) every time you want the data. (But even then, they could have just had it call `require` each time.)